# Get the ArrayList index of an element after using a row filter on a JTable

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, filter, jtable

I have an ArrayList containing multiple elements, each element contains the next fields:

- Name
- Address
- Age

I have a JTable to show the information contained in the ArrayList.
I have a TableRowSorter to filter the information, according to a certain field.

Let´s say after filtering I get only one element, therefore the JTable has now one row. How can I get the index of that element in the original ArrayList? Do I have to implement one more field kind of "ID"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int viewIndex = 0; // the index in the table of the unique filtered row. 
int modelIndex = table.convertRowIndexToModel();
```

`modelIndex` is the index of the row in the list backing the table model.